# Error while buffering 50.000 meters

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, buffer

I am on QGIS 3.10.1-A Coruña. I want to create a buffer of 50.000 meters around the cities on my map.

When I am using the buffer tool I get a disproportionate result (first image).

My layer is in EPSG:32629 (as seen in the second image). And the project is also in the same projection (third image).

I've tried reprojecting both layers without success. How can I check if the buffer is making some sort of conversion?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

[image]

Comment: The scale on your screenshot is 1:49 which cant be correct if the dots are cities? Maybe the buffer is correct and your polygon and dots way to small? Right click the Point layer, go to properties and make sure it is EPSG:32629. It does not have to be the same as the one chosen in QGIS map display (your Arrow).

Comment: The coordinates look like they are in decimal degrees rather than meters.

Comment: Coordinates are not UTM as EPSG32629 suggets, so you have 10 degrees buffers